# Thevenin Norton Concept

Tags: circuit-analysis, short-circuit, thevenin, norton

For the below circuit, assuming I add a short circuit between terminals A and B (let's call it Isc), howcome I can't use a KVL equation for the left loop, along with the right loop (IsR1 - IscR2 = 0)?[image]

Comment: The question is not really clear, but when you short circuit ab, Is divides between R1 and R2 according to the current divider rule. Then, the current source and both resistors will have the same voltage across them, as required by KVL.

Comment: If you short circuit a-b you have a couple of degenerated loops, and you can apply KVL to both, if you really want. Your equation is wrong, though. You assume Is flows entirely in R1, which is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you short those terminals, then the circuit will look like this:

[image]

R1 and R2 are now parallel. Hence current \$I_s\$ will divide between them. Therefore \$I_{sc} = I_s \frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2} = 5.6A\$. It is the current thru R2.

The curren thru R1 will be \$I_s-I_{sc} = 8 - 5.6 = 2.4A\$

**Mesh analysis:**

Your KVL equation is wrong. Since current sources are there, you can use supermesh analysis by simply rearranging the circuit like this:

[image]

Supermesh equations:

$$14I_0 + 6I_1 = 0$$
$$I_1 - I_0 = 8 mA$$

On solving you get: \$I_0 = -2.4A\$ and \$I_1 = 5.6A\$

Note that \$I_1\$ is the same as \$I_{sc}\$

So we got the same results thru mesh analysis.

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution. However, howcome it's acceptable to rearrange the circuit elements like that?

Comment: Rearranging doesn't mean you are changing the ckt. Just arranging it in away easier to understand and Analyze. Both ckts are exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write down a KVL equation for the left loop when using mesh analysis because the loop contains a current source, for which we cannot express the voltage as a simple function of the loop current. It's a common mistake to assume that the voltage across a current source is zero when using mesh analysis, but this would give an incorrect equation.

See also my related answer here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/369527/181090

Comment: If you were to use KCL, then would you ignore R1, as all of the current would go to the short circuit?

Comment: No - because R2 is still present, so you would need to consider current division (you have two resistors in parallel in this case).